# Android TextBoxes refresh after OnActivityResult is called

Tags: android

Everytime i select a from the AcitvityResult function below. My Activity refresh and previously set data from this activity is reset to empty. Through analysis, i think it has to do with onActivityResult. My question is is it possible to prevent activity result to refresh the activity because i dont want to loose previously set data. here is my onactivity result function.

**Update:**
ClassA.class

```
final Button btnValidate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnValidate);
        btnValidate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mSelectedCalendar != null) {
                    final Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(String.valueOf(Utils
                            .CalenderToInteger(mSelectedCalendar)));
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                } else {
                    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                }
                finish();
            }
        });
```

ClassB.class

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DEPARTURE_DATE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Calendar cal = Utils.IntegerToCalendar(Integer.parseInt(data
                .getAction()));
        Utils.setDate(mTxtDepartureDate, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        if (mTxtReturnDate.getTag() != null) {
            Date departureDate = (Date) mTxtDepartureDate.getTag();
            Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal2.setTime(departureDate);

            Utils.SetDayElapsed(cal2, 7);
            Utils.setDate(mTxtReturnDate, cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_RETURN_DATE
            && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Calendar cal = Utils.IntegerToCalendar(Integer.parseInt(data
                .getAction()));
        Utils.setDate(mTxtReturnDate, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
}
```

Comment: if you dont want to lose previous data then save it to saveinstancestate, or don't override your data in onactivityresult

Comment: "don't override your data in onactivityresult", should i write it in onresume ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can guess of 2 senarios:

1. You have called `finish()` when you call `startActivityForResult()`,
   the base activity(along with the useful information) might have been
   destroyed.
2. You might have created the first activity with
   `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`. If that is the case, the activity gets
   destroyed (along with the useful information) once it is brought to
   behind.

In both the cases, you can check if the previous activity was destroyed or not by adding log to the activity in `onDestroy()` of the first activity.

Comment: look at my updated questions the two class involved are shown

Comment: Did you try to add log in onDestroy() method of the ClassA activity? Is that log printed when ClassB activity is called?

Comment: thanks but i change the activity to dialog activity and it solve my issue